# Silverlight: Can I put interaction triggers into resources for reuse?

Tags: silverlight

I have a bunch of controls using identical interactions triggers across multiple user controls and viewmodels. Is it possible to place these triggers somehow into a resource dictionary for reuse? Here's an example of what a control might look like.

```
       <TextBox x:Name="FirstName" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
                    <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="KeyPressed" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBox>

       <TextBox x:Name="Initial" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
                    <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="KeyPressed" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBox>

       <TextBox x:Name="LastName" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
                    <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="KeyPressed" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBox>
```

The `cal:` namespace is from the Caliburn.Micro MVVM framework and probably isn't relevant to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not possible to re-use a single instance of `Interaction.Triggers` in a resource because it becomes attached a control.  That attachment becomes part of its state hence a single instance can't be shared by multiple controls.

You would need to include the `Interaction.Triggers` in a template so that multiple instances are created.  I guess something like the following might work, (warning air code).

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <DataTemplate x:key="MyTextBox">
      <TextBox>
          <i:Interaction.Triggers>
              <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
                  <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="KeyPressed" />
              </i:EventTrigger>
          </i:Interaction.Triggers>
      </TextBox>
   </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

...

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="FirstName" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyTextBox}" />
<ContentPresenter x:Name="Initial" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyTextBox}" />
<ContentPresenter x:Name="LastName" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyTextBox}" />
```

It my opinion that this sort of stuff isn't worth it.  The Interaction Triggers stuff is really aimed at empowering the designer rather than the developer.  A designer isn't that worried that there is some repeatition in the "code".

Comment: I'm not shure, but [x:Shared="false"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx) may help.

Comment: @Alpha-mouse: Not in Silverlight.

Comment: That's great, thanks for the answer and especially the explanation. I think at this stage I'll just duplicate the triggers where needed because the content presenters make the code less readable in this instance. Do you agree?

Comment: @Martin: Yes I do.  TBH if you are "reading" the code rather than GUIing it up in Blend then you are a developer and therefore if you really wanted to eliminate the duplication you'd write code and loose the triggers altogether.

Answer (score 1):

i have something useful in case you don't have solve completely your issue about reusing Interaction Triggers...

```
<TextBox x:Name="FirstName" KeyDown="_KeyDown">
```

...

```
private void TextBlock_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
     Here goes something you wanna reuse for all your TextBox controls..
}
```

Maybe the better option is to use a design pattern like MVVM and EventToCommand Interactions by [GalaSoft](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm)